# Converting Image in OpenCV to same color space as Photoshop

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, adobe, photoshop

I am trying to de-noise a .tif image using OpenCV's bilateralFilter() method which is working.

However when I use cv.imwrite() to save the image, it is being saved in the BGR color format from openCV.

I want to save the image in the same color space as Adobe Photoshop.
I have attached the same image saved in photoshop and also the image saved from opencv for comparison.

OpenCV Image and Photoshop Image Comparison

[image: 1]

The color between the two is very different in comparison. How can I save the file after the openCV changes to look like a typical .tiff file being opened in photoshop.

Any Help Is Appreciated!

I tried to convert the OpenCV image to RGB after I performed the bilateralFilter, but the openCV RGB is also different from what I see from opening the original image in Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here: oCV uses BGR (as default) while having a color image in memory. When you write it to file, imwrite() uses whatever encoding you're telling it to via the file extension.

Comment: Yes I understand that openCV uses BGR as default, and I also understand that using imwrite() will use the encoding thats based on the file extension.  How can I perform bilateralFilter() to de-noise and save the image, and still have the color look the same as the original image?

Comment: You can change the colorspace of a cvMat using````dst = cv2.cvtColor(src, switch)
```` with different switches like ````BGR2RGB```` etc. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0

What i'd try first though is not writing as JPG, but PNG or TIFF, see if that works better.